# Javascript on mobile site is making screen too wide

Tags: javascript

Here's the site:

http://philly.thedrinknation.com/mobile

On smartphones, the screen is too wide - allowing you to scroll to the right a little bit, rather than being exact fit.

On a desktop you can reproduce this in FF, make your browser about 350 px wide, then use the keyboard arrows to scroll right.

I have narrowed this down to the javascript from sharethis:

http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js

If I take out that call, the page is fine.  Add it back in (even on pages not using the widget), and the scrolling comes back.

It looks like they modified their code back in March, and I'm guessing that might be related.  I asked them about it, but so far no response.

Can anyone give me pointers on debugging this further?  I will copy the .js file locally to edit it if need be, but so far I can't see what is causing the problem.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem in Firefox. But you probably have to look into CSS. Don't think it will come from the AddThis Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, your issue isn't caused by javascript. Rather, it's caused by styles that AddThis is using. The `#stwrapper` element used by AddThis has an explicit width of 354px that is causing your issue. The problem is caused by this css coming in an AddThis stylesheet (hosted by them):

```
.stwrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 354px; /* This is causing the issue. The width of this element ensures that the page can never be smaller than 354px */
    z-index: 1000000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: auto;
}
```

As this stylesheet is coming from AddThis and you don't have control over it, you need to override the styles in your own stylesheet while ensuring that AddThis still works as intended.

I can't see where you're actually using AddThis, so it's hard for me to suggest what style adjustment you should make that will fix the width issue and keep AddThis working, but something like the following would be a good start:

```
.stwrapper {
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this pointed me where I needed to be.  I ended up making a local copy of the .js file, then not calling that class at all.  Didn't seem to alter the functionality we were using, so I'm going with it.  Thanks!